# Python BeautifulSoup && Request to scrape search engines

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm a little confused on how to do this. I'm not sure if this is correct but I'm trying to query a search via a url. I've tried doing this:

```
url = 'https://duckduckgo.com/dogs?ia=meanings'
session = requests.session()
r = session.get(url)
soup = bs(r.content, 'html.parser')
```

I get some html back from the response; however, when I look for all the links it comes up with nothing besides the original search url.

```
links = soup.find_all('a')
for link in links:
    print(link)

<a href="https://duckduckgo.com/html/?q=dogs">here</a>
```

When I do the search on a browser and inspect the html code, all the links exist, but for some reason are not coming back to me via my request.

Anyone have any ideas, I'm trying to build a web-scraping application and I thought this would be something really easy that I could incorporate into my terminal.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that the search results and most of the page are *dynamically loaded* with the help of JavaScript code being executed by the browser. `requests` would only download the initial static HTML page, it has no JS engine since it is not a browser.

You have basically 3 main options:

- use `DuckDuckGo` API ([Python wrapper](https://github.com/crazedpsyc/python-duckduckgo), may be there is a better one - please recheck) - this option is preferred
- load the page in a real browser through [`selenium`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) and then parse the HTML which is now the same complete HTML that you see in your browser
- try to explore what requests are made to load the page and mimic them in your `BeautifulSoup`+`requests` code. This is the hardest and the most fragile approach that may involve complex logic and javascript code parsing.